# How can I change my clothes?

Tags: apb-reloaded

I began playing APB Reloaded today, and I got some spare clothes to use, but I don't know how to wear them.

I open my inventory and there is not an option or at least I don't see it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join a Social district then press M for the map and look for the nearest Clothing Portal (Pink/Purple) there you can change and buy clothes. You can also put patterns on them and change colours.

Patterns can be made at the Designer Portal (Light Blue) Here you can create/Edit patterns/designs wich can be put on clothes and cars

If you need help ingame just try to contact people using the /district command in your Chat window

Comment: `/district` command aint helping much you know.. There are no private messages on APB?

Comment: /district is for speaking to the whole district im sure there will be some people that are willing to help you if you ask your questions there. There are private messages in the form of Mails you can send them at the mailterminals. These messages can be send whether the user is offline or online. or you can use (/wisper PlayerName Message) if you stil have questions you can mail to ForT3X thats my IGN

Comment: Quick note, you can use /d and /w instead of typing out the entire word.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE! Can you summarize the contents of this video so that we still have an answer should it disappear?