# In APB Reloaded, how do I change outfits?

Tags: apb-reloaded

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change my clothes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23618/how-can-i-change-my-clothes)

I have tried every button on the screen but it doesn't work. I want to change to the new clothes I won in the game.

I wish there were better instructions or that they would make the game easier to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to the Social District in order to customize your clothing, death themes, symbols, vehicles, and weapons. Once there, you can find stalls scattered around the district which you can use for customization.

[image: Stalls]